# Question about "unions" of a collection of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this may seem like a weird question but suppose we have an arbitrary collection of distinct non empty sets $\{U_x\}.$ And say we create a new collection of sets made by 'arbitrary unions' of $U_x.$ Will $\{U_x\}$ be contained in our new collection? Because unions always seem to involve at least 2 sets.

Comment: See [Union of a collection of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions): the general concep is defined for an arbitrary collection of sets. A special case is with two sets only.

Comment: Not clear... If $\{ U_x \mid x \in X \}$ is the collection, **the** union is a set defined by: $z \in \bigcup U_x \text { iff } \exists x (z \in U_x)$.

Comment: The *union* is the ... "re-union" in a single set of all elements of the sets in the collection.

Comment: No, except under special conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "naive" setting, you think about the union as a binary operator, like addition. But formally in set theory, and especially when talking about "arbitrary unions", the union operator is actually an unary operator taking a *family of sets*, and returning the union of the sets in that family. And a family of sets can be a singleton, and the union over a singleton $\{A\}$ is exactly $A$ itself.

But even more is true.

If you think about addition as a summation operator which takes an arbitrary number of numbers, and returns the sum, then it is perfectly fine to take sums of length $1$.  So just like "arbitrary finite summations over a set" would end up to include the original set, arbitrary unions of subfamilies will also include the original family.